# PyQt | Python 3 | «Пробежка по словарю» | вывод инфо в QMessageBox

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, qmessagebox

В программе есть словарь `f = {"742": "Ветеринарные услуги", ...}`.

Смысл программы, чтобы пользователь вводил значение в строку 
`QLineEdit` (talk_here) и значение сопоставлялось со списком.

Например, пользователь вводит ключ: "**`1771`**", а ему в `QMessageBox` выводится значение: "Подрядчики бетонных работ".

Если Вам не трудно, пожалуйста, оставьте комментарии, чтобы было более понятно.

---

**design.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 200)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("unnamed.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.talk_here = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.talk_here.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 141, 21))
        self.talk_here.setText("")
        self.talk_here.setMaxLength(4)
        self.talk_here.setObjectName("talk_here")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 160, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.pushButton.setCheckable(False)
        self.pushButton.setFlat(True)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 111, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(11, 81, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(92, 81, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(MainWindow.close)
        self.talk_here.returnPressed.connect(self.pushButton_2.click)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MCC Glossary"))
        self.talk_here.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите МСС код:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Показать весь\n"
"МСС список"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Забыли МСС код?"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окей"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Закрыть"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Показать весь МСС список"))
        self.action.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+Q"))
```

**************************main.py**************************

```
import sys
# Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from design import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

# НАЧАЛО #
        f = {
"742"   :   "Ветеринарные услуги"   ,
"763"   :   "Сельско-хозяйственные кооперативные общества"  ,
"780"   :   "Ландшафтные и садоводческие магазины"  ,
"1520"  :   "Генеральные подрядчики - жилищное и торговое строительство"    ,
"1711"  :   "Генеральные подрядчики по вентиляции, теплоснабжению, и водопроводу"   ,
"1731"  :   "Подрядчики по электричеству"   ,
"1740"  :   "Изоляция, мозаика, штукатурные работы, каменная кладка, облицовка плиткой, кафелем"    ,
"1750"  :   "Подрядчики плотничных работ"   ,
"1761"  :   "Кровельные и работы, наружная обшивка стен, подрядчики жестяницких работ"  ,
"1771"  :   "Подрядчики бетонных работ" ,
"1799"  :   "Подрядчики, специализированная торговля - нигде более не классифицированные"   ,
"2741"  :   "Разнообразные издательства/ печатное дело" ,
"2791"  :   "Набор текстов, шрифтов, таблиц и относящиеся к этому услуги"   ,
"2842"  :   "Специальная обработка, полировка, санитария"   ,
"3000"  :   "United airlines"   ,
            }
        
##Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)
                
        
               
##Функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку              
    def MyFunction(self):
       f = open('mcc_list.txt')
       print (f.read())
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: @Александр не понимаю, каким образом вводимый текст использовать для поиска значений.

В консоли всё работает, но в UI - не понимаю как это сделать.
_____________________________________________
https://pastebin.com/r55psCfJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from design_Ui import Ui_MainWindow 

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, f, parent=None):                        # + f
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.f = f                                             # +

        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)  # +++ _2

    ## Функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку `pushButton_2 !!!` 
    def MyFunction(self):
#       f = open('mcc_list.txt')                                # ???
#       print (f.read())

        name = self.f.get(self.ui.talk_here.text(), 0)
        if name:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Yes', 
                'Kлюч `{}` значение: `{}`'.format(self.ui.talk_here.text(), name))
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'No', 
                'Нет ключа `{}`'.format(self.ui.talk_here.text()))        


f = {
    "742"   :   "Ветеринарные услуги"   ,
    "763"   :   "Сельско-хозяйственные кооперативные общества"  ,
    "780"   :   "Ландшафтные и садоводческие магазины"  ,
    "1520"  :   "Генеральные подрядчики - жилищное и торговое строительство"    ,
    "1711"  :   "Генеральные подрядчики по вентиляции, теплоснабжению, и водопроводу"   ,
    "1731"  :   "Подрядчики по электричеству"   ,
    "1740"  :   "Изоляция, мозаика, штукатурные работы, каменная кладка, облицовка плиткой, кафелем"    ,
    "1750"  :   "Подрядчики плотничных работ"   ,
    "1761"  :   "Кровельные и работы, наружная обшивка стен, подрядчики жестяницких работ"  ,
    "1771"  :   "Подрядчики бетонных работ" ,
    "1799"  :   "Подрядчики, специализированная торговля - нигде более не классифицированные"   ,
    "2741"  :   "Разнообразные издательства/ печатное дело" ,
    "2791"  :   "Набор текстов, шрифтов, таблиц и относящиеся к этому услуги"   ,
    "2842"  :   "Специальная обработка, полировка, санитария"   ,
    "3000"  :   "United airlines"   ,
}
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin(f)                                         # + f
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чудесно!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Большое Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Получите вводимый текст с помощью 
text = talk_here.toPlainText()
и уже эту переменную сравнивайте с вашим списком.

Comment: Отлично! Большое спасибо!!